# PivotTable layout problems

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Am converting an old Excel 2003 workbook to 2013.  It has a pivottable which connects to an SQL Server table using OLAP query, and I've had to completely redo the PivotTable using an ODBC DSN to the data source, because the OLAP thing isn't working in 2013 for some reason, possible a Citrix issue.

I've converted the workbook to 2013 format and created a new pivot table from the same data source, but cannot get it to look right.

See the table created in 2003 versus 2013 in the link below

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MPOqE4Mj68flBz63yI7vbL6gXmMP1_dC7DPQ0oxS2Ao/edit?usp=sharing

1. The fields that are designated as 'rows' are appearing 'nested' in the 2013 table, whereas they appear as multiple columns in 2003. Also, you can filter on Doc Type in the 2003 table but not the 2013
2. The date field has been put as the column, and I've kind of worked out how to get it to split it by date (with some trial and error), but notice how in 2003 it shows the date of the month differently (i.e. the day's number only, not the day + the month, e.g. 1 instead of 1-Apr.).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2013, the default layout of PivotTable is "Compact Form" (which you called "nested"). The layout in 2003 is Tabular Form and it is still available in 2013.

1. Click on the PivotTable
2. Go to PivotTable Tools (a tab on the top)
3. Design>Report Layout
   [image]
4. Show in Tabular Form
5. Once you have change it into Tabular Form, "Doc Type" should display as an individual column and you can filter it.
   *Order of rows and columns can be adjusted by dragging.
6. The format of data field can be modified in Field Settings. Right click on the desired cell, and look for "Value Field Setting".